# monitoring azure-iot deployments via azure-cli

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-cli, azure-iot-edge

### Background

I'm using `Azure-cli` (version >2.3.1) to [create IoT Edge deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-iot-ext/iot/edge/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest):

```
echo az iot edge deployment create --content $(iotDeploymentPath) --deployment-id $(deploymentId) --hub-name  ${hub} --priority $(priority) --target-condition "tags.location.place='$(env)'"
```

and for [getting the metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-iot-ext/iot/edge/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-cli-iot-ext-az-iot-edge-deployment-show-metric):

```
targetedCount="$(az iot edge deployment show-metric --deployment-id $(deploymentId) --metric-id targetedCount  --hub-name ${hub})"
appliedCount="$(az iot edge deployment show-metric --deployment-id $(deploymentId) --metric-id appliedCount  --hub-name ${hub})"
reportedSuccessfulCount="$(az iot edge deployment show-metric --deployment-id $(deploymentId) --metric-id reportedSuccessfulCount   --hub-name ${hub})"
```

A few days ago, we got the following error message while trying to receive the deployment's metrics:

> the metric 'targetedCount' is not defined in the device configuration
> $(deploymentId)
>
> the metric 'appliedCount' is not defined in the device configuration
> $(deploymentId)
>
> the metric 'reportedSuccessfulCount' is not defined in the device
> configuration $(deploymentId)

with the following depracation message:

> This extension 'azure-cli-iot-ext' is deprecated and scheduled for
> removal. Please remove and add 'azure-iot' instead.

So I've installed 'azure-iot' instead of 'azure-cli-iot-ext', but now it seems like
`az iot edge deployment show-metric` stopped working and keeps sending the error message mentioned above.

> the metric 'targetedCount' is not defined in the device configuration
> $(deploymentId)
>
> the metric 'appliedCount' is not defined in the device configuration
> $(deploymentId)
>
> the metric 'reportedSuccessfulCount' is not defined in the device
> configuration $(deploymentId)

### Question:

How can I get those `metrics` back **without** having the CLI deprecated extanstion version?

Comment: When you say  the `az iot edge deployment show-metric` "stopped working", what do you mean? Is there an error?

Comment: I use the same in a pipeline and just looked at my logs and everything seems to be working. Is your pipeline passing the `deploymentId` parameter through properly? The error looks to be as though it cannot parse the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting Azure support team answer:

> I just received an update from our Product Group. They have informed
> me that before azure-cli-iot-ext 0.8.7, iot edge deployment
> show-metric would only work against system metrics. After, an argument
> was introduced for the user to be able to switch between system and
> user metrics but to match iot hub configuration show-metric, the user
> metrics became the default (which carried over to azure-iot).
>
> In addition, the PG member pointed out that all the metrics causing
> issues with appear to be system metrics. In that case, please try
> adding the --metric-type or –mt argument with value ‘system’.
>
> For example:
>
> `az iot edge deployment show-metric -n myiothub -d mydeployment -m targetedCount --mt system`